# How to integrate Imebra v5 to a swift command line project

Tags: swift, xcode, imebra

I'm trying to import Imebra into a basic swift 5 command line project using Xcode 12. I followed the official [steps](https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/html/html/compiling_imebra.html#using-imebra-with-swift) but I failed. I can summarise the whole structure:

The structure of the project is just

```
./
├── main.swift
├── Data
   └── DX_0.dcm
├── Imebra
   └── CMakeLists.txt
   └── docs
   └── examples
   └── library
   └── test
   └── wrappers
   └── build_imebra_macos
```

The main swift file is

```swift
// main.swift

import Foundation

print("Hello, Imebra!")

do {
   let pDataSet = try ImebraCodecFactory.load(fromFile: "PathToDicomFileFromExecutable")
    let pImage = try pDataSet.getImageApplyModalityTransform(0)
   print("The image width is", pImage.width)
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Following the documentation, I compile the library by going to the `build_imebra_macos` folder and running

```
build_imebra_macos % cmake -GXcode -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
build_imebra_macos % cmake --build . --config Release
```

The build is successful and the new folder Release has the dynamic library. Now in Xcode project of the CL Swift application, SwiftyImebra.xcodeproj, I followed the next instruction "open the target Build Settings and under “Swift Compiler/ObjectiveC Bridging Header” specify the path to imebra_location/wrappers/objectivec/include/imebraobjc/imebra.h.”, with Imebra_location changed to Imebra.

Then when I build I get the error

```
Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ImebraCodecFactory
```

I'm new in Swift and I guess I need to specify somewhere in Xcode where the source or the dynamic library is. However, I am not sure about this either as we have generated a cpp dynamic library so this can only interact with objective-C (?). I apologise if this is a basic question...

In addition, I'd like to learn how to use Imebra as a static library with swift.

Answer (score 0):

The imebra dynamic library must be added to the project.

Drag the imebra.dylib (generated into your build folder build_imebra_macos) into your project.

Additionally, specify the folder containing the dylib into the "Library search path" in the compiler options.

Comment: Hi Paolo! After dragging the generated .dylib files into "Link Binary With Libraries" (Build Phases) and specifying the Library Path I got at runtime:
```dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libimebra.5.dylib
  Referenced from: 
PathToDerivedDataFolder
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/lib/libimebra.5.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libimebra.5.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
```

Comment: I would not like to remove the validation layer. I checked the signatures again and they are in development.

Comment: Move the library to the location where the executable is so it can find it when it runs, or configure xcode to copy the dll to the executable location.

Comment: I found out that the dylib must be also build with Team ID. It didn't need to copy/move the dll to the executable as long as the folder was specified in "Library Search Paths". Xcode12 seems to be more restrictive

Comment: A better way though, would be to use XCODE_EMBED_FRAMEWORKS and set the target PROPERTY `XCODE_EMBED_FRAMEWORKS_CODE_SIGN_ON_COPY` to TRUE. Could you maybe add this hints as well to your answer and I will accept it?

Comment: The hardcoded, not recommended, way was to change the Imebra's main project CMakeList.txt file with
```cmake
project("imebra")
# Signing & Capabilities
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM   "YOURTEAM")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "Apple Development")
```
and then generate and build as in the Description of this question.